# What is the radius of convergence of a power series in two variables?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, several-complex-variables

What is the radius of convergence of a power series in two real variables?

If I were to fix one of the variables (i.e. make it a real constant), then would the radius of convergence simply be related to the nearest singularity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A power series in several complex variables doesn't have a radius of convergence. In general, the domain of convergence is a logaritmically convex Reinhardt domain, but not necessarily a ball. Consider for example the series
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k w^k \qquad\text{and}\qquad \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^j w^k$$
respectively.

Comment: What if the variables were only allowed to take real values?

Comment: That doesn't matter. (Besides, the natural way to study power series is with complex variables.)

Comment: So only power series in a single variable have a radius of convergence in general. Ok, thanks.

Comment: What of I were to fix one of the variables? Then it would effectively become a power series in only one variable, right?

Comment: Right. For each fixed value of $w$ say, you get a power series in the other variable, which has a radius of convergence (depending on $w$).

Comment: In your answer should $k$ run from $0$ to $j$, and not $\infty$?

Comment: I intended the example as stated. Note that the first series doesn't even have a *bounded* domain of convergence.

Comment: If $z$ and $w$ are real, then $|zw|<1$ would work ?

Comment: i am curious about with  Pixel's last question,too. any answer please? @mrf

Comment: @user1062 The first series converges for $|zw|<1$, (real or not).